# Why am I getting a null pointer exception when assigning names to my players?

Tags: java, android

I have an android activity where the user specifies the number of players in a game, and the points needed to win the game. Once the user clicks "Start", a new Game object is supposed to be created with however many Player objects. I have already validated that the numbers are being pulled from the EditText Views properly, but for some reason, I  receive a null pointer exception from my Game class at the line:

```
players[i].name = "Player " + i;
```

Here's code from my Game class, there is also a Player class that has a data member name (which I didn't include).

```
 public class Game{
  public int i;
  public int numOfPlayers;
  public int maxScore;
  Player[] players;

      public Game(int numOfPlayers, int maxScore){
          this.maxScore = maxScore;
          this.numOfPlayers = numOfPlayers;

          players= new Player[numOfPlayers];
           for(i =0; i<numOfPlayers;i++){
              players[i].name = "Player " + i;
          }
  }
 }
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to instantiate each player object as well as the array:

```
for(i =0; i<numOfPlayers;i++){
   players[i] = new Player();
   players[i].name = "Player " + i;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I knew it was something simple, but I just couldn't see it. I'll mark the answer as accepted as soon as the 15 minute window clears.

Answer (score 6):

You created the array, but you didn't create any Players.  When you created the array, all spots in the array are initially null.

Create the player, then assign its name.

```
players[i] = new Player();
players[i].name = "Player " + i;
```